# Limit how much elements scrapy can collect

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using scrapy to collect some data. My scrapy program collects 100 elements at one session. I need to limit it to 50 or any random number. How can i do that? Any solution is welcomed. Thanks in advance

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import scrapy


class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["raleigh.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/bab"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://raleigh.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = self.BASE_URL + "reply/ral/bab/" + item_id

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"] = "".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
            return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_contact)

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`CloseSpider` extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#scrapy.contrib.closespider.scrapy.contrib.closespider.CloseSpider) and `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` setting were made for:

> An integer which specifies a number of items. If the spider scrapes
>   more than that amount if items and those items are passed by the item
>   pipeline, the spider will be closed with the reason
>   closespider_itemcount. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t be closed
>   by number of passed items.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941439/2284676) answer but I had to combine all 3 limits to make it work, so leaving it here just in case someone else is having the same issue:

```
class GenericWebsiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """This generic website spider extracts text from websites"""

    name = "generic_website"

    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 15,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 15,
        'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 15
    }
...
```